# Can't get OpenVPN to work

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, firewalld

I'm trying to set up OpenVPN to access my remote server's internal network and its Internet connection but I can't seem to get it work.

My server's network interfaces:

```
ens32: WAN (10.10.1.11/24)
ens33: Local network (10.11.1.1/24)
tun0: OpenVPN (10.11.2.1/24)
```

My server runs Ubuntu 18.04, firewalld and OpenVPN 2.4.4. It acts as a NAT gateway to `ens33` using the following:

1. `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
2. `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=ens32`
3. `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-interface=ens33`
4. `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-interface=tun0`
5. `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade`

I want my VPN client on `tun0` to be able to access other servers on `ens33` and my server's Internet connection. However, the following things happen when the client (Windows 10 and OpenVPN 2.4.7, `10.11.2.2`) is connected to the VPN:

1. The client cannot access the Internet.
   `ping` result of `www.google.com`:

```
Pinging www.google.com [172.217.27.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.1.2: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 10.10.1.2: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 10.10.1.2: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 10.10.1.2: TTL expired in transit.
```

`tracert` result of `www.google.com`:

```
Tracing route to www.google.com [172.217.27.4]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.11.2.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.10.1.2
  3     3 ms    46 ms    44 ms  10.11.2.1
  4    43 ms    48 ms    50 ms  10.10.1.2
  5     2 ms    47 ms    49 ms  10.11.2.1
  6     6 ms    48 ms    46 ms  10.10.1.2
  7     3 ms    49 ms    48 ms  10.11.2.1
  8     2 ms    46 ms    52 ms  10.10.1.2
  9     9 ms    48 ms    28 ms  10.11.2.1
  ...
```

P.S. `10.10.1.2` is the gateway of my server's WAN interface (`ens32`).

2. The client can ping another server in my server's `ens33` (`10.11.1.21`), but it can't access the HTTP server on it.
   `tracert` result of `10.11.1.21`:

```
Tracing route to 10.11.1.21 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.11.2.1
  2     3 ms     2 ms     3 ms  10.11.1.21
```

Firefox shows `Unable to connect` error.

3. `10.11.1.21` lose connectivity to my server (`10.11.1.1`) and the Internet.

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Pinging `10.11.1.1` results in 100% packet loss.
They work perfectly fine when the client is not connected to my server.

---

`server.conf`:

```
port             10000
proto            tcp
dev              tun

ca               /etc/openssl/server/ca.crt
cert             /etc/openssl/server/server.crt
key              /etc/openssl/server/server.key
dh               none
tls-crypt        /etc/openssl/server/ta.key 0

tls-version-min  1.2
ecdh-curve       prime256v1
cipher           AES-128-GCM

topology         subnet

server           10.11.2.0 255.255.255.0

push             "route 10.11.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push             "redirect-gateway autolocal def1 bypass-dhcp"
push             "remote-gateway 10.11.2.1"
push             "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"

keepalive        10 120

max-clients      10

user             nobody
group            nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status           /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append       /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-log.log
verb             4
mute             20
```

`client.conf`:

```
client
proto            tcp
remote           10.10.1.11 10000
dev              tun
nobind

ca               "D:/vpn/client/key/ca.crt"
cert             "D:/vpn/client/key/client.crt"
key              "D:/vpn/client/key/client.key"
dh               none
tls-crypt        "D:/vpn/client/key/ta.key" 1

tls-client
tls-version-min  1.2
ecdh-curve       prime256v1
cipher           AES-128-GCM

auth-nocache

remote-cert-tls  server

resolv-retry     infinite

persist-key
persist-tun

verb             4

mute             20
```

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to add the raw iptables output, I don't know what `firewall-cmd` does. Run `iptables -t nat -L -vn; iptables -L -vn` and add that output to your question.

Comment: @wurtel turns out it's a configuration issue on my end.

I run the servers in VMware Workstation to test my configuration before pushing it to my actual server and `10.10.1.11/24` is a NAT adapter and its gateway is my client machine. This will definitely cause routing loop when I try to access the VPN from the client. I'm surprised why I didn't notice it earlier.

I've just pushed the same configuration to my actual server and it works.

Thanks for your help.